# Can't get toggling between two colors for div when clicking a link to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

I have this link:

```
<div id='up_arrow_div'> 
<%= link_to "&uArr;".html_safe, video_votes_path( :video_id => video.id, :type => "up" ), :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => 'up_arrow' %>
</div>
```

as well as a down vote one that sends a POST request and inserts a vote into the database. I'm trying to set up styling so that it changes colors when you click it. Here's the initial CSS:

```
a.up_arrow:link, a.down_arrow:link {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;  
font-size: 25px;
margin-left: 7px;
}

#up_arrow_div, #down_arrow_div {
display:block;
background-color:#DFEAF4;
width:30px;
}
```

The CSS creates a colored square div around the arrow-shaped link. Then I have this jQuery:

```
$('a.up_arrow').toggle(function () {
    $('#up_arrow_div').css("background-color", "#19558D");
     }, function () {
        $('#up_arrow_div').css("background-color", "#E9DEDE;"); 
 });

 $('a.down_arrow').toggle(function() {
     $('#down_arrow_div').css("background-color", "#19558D");
 }, function () {
         $('#down_arrow_div').css("background-color", "#E9DEDE;");  
 });
```

This doesn't seem to work though. What happens is that first of all, the voting becomes disabled. Also, the color of the div changes once, but it doesn't change back when you click it again. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

UPDATE:

As requested, here is the generated HTML markup:

```
<div id="voting_div">
  <div id="up_arrow_div">   
  <a href="/video_votes?type=up&amp;video_id=448" class="up_arrow" data-method="post" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">⇑</a>
  </div>
  <div id="vote_display">
    <p id="votes">0 Votes</p>
  </div>
  <div id="down_arrow_div">
  <a href="/video_votes?type=down&amp;video_id=448" class="down_arrow" data-method="post" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">⇓</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE 2:

Here's the JS code I'm using now, as explained by the answer below:

```
    var toggleVoting = function() {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass("voted")) {
            return "unvoted";
        }
        else {
            return "voted";
        }
    };

    $('a.up_arrow').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass(toggleVoting);
    });

    $('a.down_arrow').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass(toggleVoting);
    });
```

The behavior of this code is that when I vote, the div has the class `voted` added to it, and when I vote again, the `voted` class is removed, but the `unvoted` class is not added. I need to add the `unvoted` class when the `voted` class is removed.

Comment: Can you include the generated HTML markup? I can't 'read' Ruby code.

Comment: Yep, just edited the question details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the semicolons (`;`) from the color you're passing to `.css()` in your second toggle function for each selector (`#E9DEDE` instead of `#E9DEDE;`):

```
$('a.up_arrow').toggle(function () {
    $('#up_arrow_div').css("background-color", "#19558D");
     }, function () {
        $('#up_arrow_div').css("background-color", "#E9DEDE"); 
 });

 $('a.down_arrow').toggle(function() {
     $('#down_arrow_div').css("background-color", "#19558D");
 }, function () {
         $('#down_arrow_div').css("background-color", "#E9DEDE");  
 });
```

**Update:** As you pointed out, the link won't be followed when the `toggle()` code is applied. This is because jQuery cancels the default action of the link when that function is executed. To get around that, you could write your own code that uses `toggleClass()` instead:

**JavaScript:**

```
var toggleVoting = function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("voted")) {
        return "unvoted";
    }
    else {
        return "voted";
    }
};

$('a.up_arrow').click(function() {
    $("#up_arrow_div").toggleClass(toggleVoting);
});

$('a.down_arrow').click(function() {
    $("#down_arrow_div").toggleClass(toggleVoting);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.voted { background-color: #19558D; }
.unvoted { background-color: #E9DEDE; }
```

**Update 2:** To remove `voted`/`unvoted`:

```
var toggleVoting = function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass("voted")) {
        $this.removeClass("voted");
        return "unvoted";
    }
    else {
        $this.removeClass("unvoted");
        return "voted";
    }
};
```

---

**Update 3, based on comments below:**

```
var toggleVoting = function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass("voted")) {
        $this.removeClass("voted");
        return "unvoted";
    }
    else {
        $this.removeClass("unvoted");
        return "voted";
    }
};

$('a.up_arrow').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $downArrow = $("#down_arrow_div");
    if ($downArrow.hasClass("voted")) {
        $downArrow.addClass("unvoted").removeClass("voted");
    }
    $("#up_arrow_div").toggleClass(toggleVoting);
});

$('a.down_arrow').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $upArrow = $("#up_arrow_div");
    if ($upArrow.hasClass("voted")) {
        $upArrow.addClass("unvoted").removeClass("voted");
    }
    $("#down_arrow_div").toggleClass(toggleVoting);    
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/QuA2K/2/

Comment: cool this makes the color toggle work. The voting is disabled now though... Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Also, if I delete the toggle JS code, the voting works, so it must be something related to the jQuery code.

Comment: @Justin: I have a hunch that toggle is canceling the default action of the link under the hood.

Comment: Hmmm, how do I make these two things play nice together?

Comment: very elegant solution :) We're almost there. When I vote, the vote class is added, but when I vote again, the unvotes class is added with the vote class. The unvoted class needs to be taken away.

Comment: ok, added the code I'm using with an explanation of how it works.

Comment: What about when the links have never been clicked, so the div has neither class? It should have the "unvoted" color. And what about right after a page refresh?

Comment: oh, and if you click the down button after clicking the up button, the colors should change for both. Maybe I should make this a new question?

Comment: @Justin: If you need to apply the class on page load, you could just put it on the anchor tags directly: `<a class='unvoted'>...</a>`

Comment: and what about clicking the down button after the up button has been clicked?

Comment: Also there's still a problem with the page reload even if I add the `unvoted` class directly to the div. Let's say I click on the link: the div changes color because the `voted` class is added to it, and the vote is added. Then I reload the page. The `unvoted` class is added back to the div by default, but the vote is still registered. Instead, the div should keep its current class after a page reload.

Comment: @Justin: Seems like you could make your server-side rendering smart enough to apply the correct classes (`voted`/`unvoted`) depending on the voting status. As for clicking the down button after the up button, I can write something that will take care of that.

Comment: I think I can figure out the server-side stuff, but I'll need help for the upvote after downvote or downvote after upvote. Thanks, Andrew.

Comment: Thanks! Will `preventDefault` get rid of the voting functionality? What is it for?

Comment: @Justin: Yes, in your production code you should remove those lines. It prevents the default action of the link, which in this case is to follow the link, but you need that functionality